# Correct way of keeping mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql

I have an application running 24/7 which uses mysql. Different functions of it use mysql. One way to implement it is to create a global mysql instance in the application like this:

```
self.db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host=self.settings.MYSQL_HOST_LOCAL,
            user=self.settings.MYSQL_USER,
            passwd=self.settings.MYSQL_PASS,
            db=self.settings.MYSQL_DB,
            use_unicode=True,
            charset="utf8",
        )
```

and execute commands using `self.db.execute(...)`. By doing this, the application uses 1 connection. The other way is to create connection every time I need to execute a transaction.

Approach 1, prevents the application from creating and deleting connections over and over but it will face "mysql gone away" problem if it stays ideal. Approach 2, doesn't have a problem with "mysql gone away", but it has too much I/O.

I am pretty sure neither these approcaches are the right ones, but what is the right approach?

Comment: " but it has too much I/O." - how have you determined that?

Comment: by too much I mean for each select or update, I create a new connection. That doesn't count as "too much"?

Comment: Approach 2 is almost always the correct approach. Let connection pooling do it's funky stuff...BTW you appear to be trying to solve a problem before you know you have one.

Comment: @MitchWheat thanx, could you please provide me with a reference?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is to create a connection every time you need to execute. You can also create a function to do it for you. This is how it meant to be. It is not too much I/O..

You can also do the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        db_session.execute('SELECT * FROM table')
        break
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        db_session.rollback()
```

If the connection has go away, this will raise an exception, the session will be rollbackd, it'll try again is likely to succeed. (The first solution is much better)

Comment: So should I close my db connection at the end of each transaction? I am using MySQLdb. Lets say I create a new instance at the beginning of my function. If I don't close it, the instance will be deleted, now what happens to the connection? Is it ok now, or should I close it before the function returns?

Answer (score 0):

In Approach 1, according to the application scenario 'MySQL server has gone away' may happens because

```
You have encountered a timeout on the server side and the automatic reconnection in the client is disabled (the reconnect flag in the MYSQL structure is equal to 0).
```

You can add a decorator to any db handler function like this to reconnect MySQL db when exception 'MySQL server has gone away' raised.

```
class DB:
    """Database interface"""

    def retry(func):
        def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
            lock.acquire()
            try:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                if 'MySQL server has gone away' in str(e):
                    # reconnect MySQL
                    self.connect_mysql()
                else:
                    # No need to retry for other reasons
                    pass
            finally:
                lock.release()
        return call

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connect_mysql(self):
        # do connection

    @retry
    def db_handler_function(self):
        # do something
```

Comment: Thanx, I thought about that, but my main question is which approach is the right one. I have a fix for both of the approaches but neither looks good enough.

Comment: some similar posts here: [mysql connections. Should I keep it alive or start a new connection before each transaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672713/mysql-connections-should-i-keep-it-alive-or-start-a-new-connection-before-each),  [Is it better to hold database connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011086/is-it-better-to-hold-database-connections)